# android-execute a worker at roughly the same time every day

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

according to [this medium article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/workmanager-periodicity-ff35185ff006) from Android Developers:

> At the moment, if you need to execute a worker at roughly the same time, every day, your best option is to use a OneTimeWorkRequest with an initial delay so that you execute it at the right time:

and then when the work finishes successfully, the idea is to reschedule the work to be run once again and so on. now my question is that if we want a work to be repeated everyday at roughly the same time, why can't we directly use work manager `PeriodicWorkRequest`? for example suppose the work must be repeated everyday around 5:00 PM. then:

```
        Calendar windowStart = new GregorianCalendar();
        windowStart.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
        windowStart.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        windowStart.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        windowStart.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        long delay = windowStart.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (delay < 0) {
            windowStart.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            delay = windowStart.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build();

        PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest =
                new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(Worker.class, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                        .setInitialDelay(delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .setConstraints(constraints)
                        .build();
```

does this piece of code guarantee that the work will definitely run everyday between 17:00 and 17:05, if the constraints are met?

Comment: check if this works https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/workmanager-periodicity-ff35185ff006

Comment: @Raghunandan I have referenced to the same article in my question!

Comment: use onetime request and when work is completed shedule another one with same time. I have done the same in of my use case. But do check new additions in work manager api.

Comment: @Raghunandan and when I want to reschedule the work, what kind of `ExistingWorkPolicy` should I use? `APPEND`?

Comment: Use ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE

Comment: @Raghunandan since we are scheduling one time workers, shouldn't it be `APPEND`?

Comment: if you want to reschedule one time request again you want to cancel any exisiting work requests then usee REPLACE. Once 1 requests is done you want another to be scheduled so i think replace works